# Visual studio 2012 showing duplicate dlls in reference manager

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In a website project, when I press add reference. All build in assemblies in .net are showing twice, and when adding one it also adds the other and fails the add.

Comment: No, cant say that I've seen this before. Is it a known assembly? Try open the .proj file with a text editor and look for the xml tag corresponding assemlby, is there twice, does it have exactly the same name?

Comment: its all .net assemblies. 4.0 and 4.5